# Combine 2 cypher queries into 1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with the graph database Neo4j. I want to combine the following two cypher queries into one.

```
START a=node(2)
MATCH (a)<-[:TYPE]-(vendrs)<-[:FROM]-(prods) 
RETURN vendrs.name, count(prods)

START a=node(2)
MATCH (a)<-[:TYPE]-(vendrs)<-[:FROM]-(prods)
WHERE(prods.r?<>-1 and prods.f?<=0 and prods.I! = 1) 
RETURN vendrs.name, count(prods)
```

Node with id 2 is a super node having nodes representing vendors related to it via TYPE relationships and from each of these nodes prods are related by FROM relationship.

I want to combine them into one so i tried:

```
START a=node(2)
MATCH (a)<-[:TYPE]-(vendrs)<-[:FROM]-(prods)
RETURN vendrs.name,
    count(prods),
    filter(count(prods) where(prods.r?<>-1 and prods.f?<=0 and prods.I! = 1));
```

But its not working? How should i correct it?

`Error:SyntaxException: Unclosed parenthesis`

Comment: WHat about `start a=node(2) 
match (a)<-[:TYPE]-(vendrs)<-[:FROM]-(prods) 
where prods.r?<>-1 and prods.f?<=0 and prods.I! = 1
return vendrs.name,count(prods)`?

Comment: So to be clear, you are trying to return a list of vendors, a total count of their products, and a count of products that meet certain conditions(a subset of the total count).  Is that accurate?

Comment: @JonathanF: yeah this is what i want to return in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what version of Neo4j, but the filter I see with 2.0 is

```
FILTER(x IN coll WHERE x.prop <> {value})
```

so I'm going to assume that what you actually want is a count of those filtered products and not a FILTER() on the COUNT()?

```
COUNT(FILTER(product IN products WHERE product.r?<>-1 AND product.f?<=0 AND product.I! = 1)) AS filterCount
```

Haven't tried this but it makes sense. Also used to full name (product instead of prodct or what ever) just to make it clear to other readers. Note i'm not sure what the '!' is, and you might be better to check performance tips on Cypher regarding all the '?' optional prams if they really must be optional.

Comment: Also, check out http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ for the syntax on optional properties using `HAS(product.f)`, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-property-exists